# Difference between ME & Current User Filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter

I was creating a sharepoint page where I wanted to input minutes of one-one with my directs - my requirement was such that if I enter the minutes of meeting - the person who's alias/email address that I input should be able to see it.
I've tried [me] filter - but it only worked if the my direct entered the comments
Current user filter didn't work apparently for some odd reason without an error

Comment: On which field you are adding the [Me] filter? In order to see the list items the current logged in user should be in that particular field/column.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/YW92B7.jpg
I've added  that on the login column

Comment: I am not very understanding of your requirement, What do you want to achieve? could you please share more detailed information?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to create pool of comments that I have for individual while I wanted them to see that belongs only to them while they login.
In the snap I shared if I enter else's login (column name), I'd want that particular person to have view and access only to that entry and not view others.
https://snipboard.io/YQvLXh.jpg

In the picture, I've created the entry, but the people in the login column aren't able to view it

Comment: When I use the [Me] in the column, it only shows up the entries that are made by the person in the login column but not what I've entered

Answer (score 0):

That is a known behavior.

If you will add `[Me]` filter on the "login" column then you will able to see only the list items where you have been added to "login" column.

If you want to show the comments you have entered then maybe you need to create another view where you will add `[Me]` filter on "Created By" column.

And if you don't want to create a new view and show all the items in same view then you can add **OR** condition in list view filter where you can define `[Me]` filter on both "login" and "Created By" column.

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).